# Scraping text() value if href contains a part of specific text

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to collect the text in `a` if `href` contains `venue/`, so I tried to do it this way:

```
var venue = $('.details > span > a:contains(href="venue/")');
sheet.getRange(3,17).setValue(venue.text().trim());
```

But returns with no value, how should I be able to retrieve such value?
As the site changes the positions of the elements from time to time, I need to define this contains.

Expected Result:

```
Estadio Manuel Ferreira (Asunción)
```

Map Example:

```
<div class="details ">
       <a href="/matches/2021/08/12/">11/08/2021</a>

       <span class="divider"></span>

       <a href="/international/south-america/copa-libertadores/2021/quarter-finals/r61990/">CONMEBOL Libertadores</a>

       <span class="divider"></span>


         <span>KO</span>
         <span>
           19:15
         </span>
      <br>
         <span>Venue</span>
         <span>
              <a href="venue/">Estadio Manuel Ferreira (Asunción)</a></span>
     </div>
```

Link to site:
https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2021/08/12/south-america/copa-libertadores/club-olimpia/clube-de-regatas-de-flamengo/3579565/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the issue is right on the first line, as the “venue” variable does not return what you expect.

I propose you select the anchor you are looking for by getting the last element of type `a` in the `div` you provided and assign the value of its `href` attribute to a variable called `venue`. After that, check if the `venue` variable is equal to `venue/`. If the condition returns `true`, get the anchor’s inner text, assign it to a variable called `result` and log it.

You can make it work by using the following code:

```
let element = $('.details a').last()
let venue = element.attr('href');

if (venue === 'venue/') {
  let result = element.text()
  console.log(result) // this is the value you are looking for
}
```

Updated:

```
let elements = $('.details a')

elements.each((index, value) => {
    let href = $(value).attr('href')
    if (href === 'venue/') {
        console.log($(value).text())
    }
})
```

Comment: Hello good Morning @DanSuciu !  Thanks in advance for your help, the problem is that as I mentioned in the question, the site sometimes changes its position, making this element no longer the last.  Is there a way to use it that can select the element from this ```href="venue/"```?

Comment: My bad, I didn’t get that from your message. In this case, we have to get all the anchor elements in the `div` container, iterate through all of them and check if the `href` attribute is equal to `venue/`. If that’s true, log the anchor’s inner text to the console. Please check my initial answer for the updated version of the code. Let me know if this works!